# Symfony2 Memcached configuration Issue

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, symfony-2.3, lsw-memcache-bundle

I am using `LswMemcacheBundle` in a  `Symfony2` application.

I configured all the configuration in my application. I installed all the plugins on `nginx` server.

When I run my application, I got following error:

```
Runtime Notice: Declaration of Lsw\MemcacheBundle\Cache\LoggingMemcache::get() should be compatible with Memcached::get($key, $cache_cb = NULL, &$cas_token = NULL, &$udf_flags = NULL)
```

I am not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: Did you install the `php5-memcached` extension and `memcached` packages ( *notice the* **`d`** *at the end* ) ? What versions of memcached, php5-memcached and php do you use ? What operating system?

Comment: memcache support => enabled,
Version => 3.0.8,
Revision => $Revision: 329835,
php version=>5.4.25,
Os: centos,
server: nginx

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in php-memcached 2.2.0 there are several ways to work around it.

- Install php-memcached 2.1.0 which does not have this bug
- Install php-memcached from master branch which has a fix
- Upgrade LswMemcachedBundle to version 2 which uses the memcache extension
- Turn off notices in error reporting ( not recommended )

This bug is well reported at [LswMemcachedBundle](https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswMemcacheBundle/issues/21) and [php-memcached project](https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/126)